# How to call a Eclipse plugin from another plugin?

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm trying to create a eclipse plugin which has to call few other eclipse plugins like SecureAssist, Findbugs..,. Is this possible?.

The ultimate motive is to check if the project passes all the rules from secure assist and fidbugs when he tries to checkin his code to RTC.

I'm fairly new to plugin creation. Any help would be helpful.

Comment: esclipse plugins are OSGi, you need to know the services the other plugin has...

Comment: You need to look at the documentation for the plug-ins to see what APIs or OSGi services they offer. Once you know that you use them like you would a core Eclipse plug-in.